# WPF datagrid selectedvalue/selecteditem bindings does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid CanUserSortColumns="False" x:Name="TablePreviewDataGrid" 
                      SelectionMode="Single" 
                      SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"  
                      SelectedValuePath="{Binding Item}"
                      SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged"
                      IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TableData}" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

And bindings:

```
private DataTable _tableData;
public DataTable TableData
{
    get { return _tableData; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _tableData, value); }
}

private object _selectedItem;
public object Item
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value); }
}
```

`Item` property is not updated when I click on grid cells. Howewer, if I remove

```
SelectionMode="Single" 
SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
```

binding works just fine.

Does someone knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

MSDN knows. If you look at the [`DataGrid.SelectionUnit` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionunit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, it says:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether rows, cells, or both can be selected in the `DataGrid`.

The most usual (and default) value is `FullRow`, so you could try this.

If you look at the [`Selector.SelectedValue` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, it sayd:

> Gets or sets the value of the `SelectedItem`, obtained by using `SelectedValuePath`.

So your first problem is that you didn't set the `SelectedValuePath` property to the name of the property that you want passed into the `SelectedValue` property. However, it is more usual to data bind an object of the same type as the items in your `DataGrid.ItemsSoucre` collection to the `SelectedItem` property, then you can bind to the whole selected item object.

I doubt that removing the `SelectionMode` property would make any difference in this case. So to fix your problem, I'd set the `DataGrid.SelectionUnit` Property to `FullRow` and data bind to the `SelectedItem` property instead of using the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` properties. You can find out further differences between these selected item properties in the [How to: Use SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: `SelectionMode` makes the difference. I need `column` selection rather then `row` selection, as a work around I use `selected cell` to get column. 

I would bind `SelectedValue` to the same type as `ItemSource` has, however `ItemSource` represents data base table, which type varies.

I dont actually need selected item itself, I need selected column for grid with auto generated columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your culprits are `SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"` and `SelectedValuePath="{Binding Item}".`

Since each row in `DataGrid` represents the data item, hence selecting full row will select the item or `SelectionUnit="FullRow"` will select the item. Else if you have other SelectionUnit then you can get `SelectedItem` by `DataGrid.SelectedCells[0].Item`

Also you don't bind `SelectedValuePath` but `SelectedValue`

Comment: The main idea is to get selected column or column header. It will be cool if bindings can be used for that, I dont want to manually track collected cell changed event.